# Azure AD App Registration via Powershell: How to ensure the proper permissions?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell

I need to register an application in Azure AD using PowerShell.  I plan to use the [New-AzADApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadapplication?view=azps-4.1.0) cmdlet. The cmdlet [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadapplication?view=azps-4.1.0#description) states the following:

> Below are the permissions needed to create an application:
>
> - Azure Active Directory Graph
>
>   - Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy
> - Microsoft Graph
>
>   - Directory.AccessAsUser.All
>   - Directory.ReadWrite.All

I've learned that these permissions are [scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-glossary#scopes), which is a new concept to me and something I don't know how to deal with in Azure. I found this [short demo](https://youtu.be/yXYzgWWVdSM?t=144), which shows these scopes can be managed as API permissions from the Azure App registration context. However, that demo shows the scopes being managed *after* the application has already been created.  How can I establish the proper scopes *before* the application is created?

Or, more generally, how can I ensure that I have the appropriate permissions to execute the `New-AzADApplication` cmdlet?

Comment: Can you use the `-RequiredResourceAccess` parameter of [`New-AzureADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) in the [AzureAD Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/ad-pshell-v2-version-history?view=azureadps-2.0)? I think you still need to use this module for such things. You could confirm what is already there with `(Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId '<AppRegistrationObjectID>').requiredResourceAccess`. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Ash you're referencing a different module, I'm using the more recent Az.Resources module.

Comment: I'm aware. The Az module can't do everything the AzureAD one can as the latter existed alongside the AzureRM modules too. Looks like from juunas' answer it isn't possible anyway yet, but he too mentions the AzureAD module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application that needs those permissions is Azure AD PowerShell in this case. If it didn't have a service principal in your AAD tenant yet, you would be asked for consent to those scopes on first login when using the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet.

In my experience, the service principal that it uses already exists in your tenant. So it already has the needed permissions. But what will also matter is your user permissions. Since it uses delegated permissions, it is acting on behalf of your user. In order for it to be able to create the app, it needs to have the necessary scope/delegated permission and your user must be able to create applications.

The cmdlets do also support acting as a service principal/app, in which case application permissions given to the app used to authenticate would apply, not delegated permissions. But that's another case that I don't think you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Applications are able to note which permissions they require (both delegated and application) in the app registration portal. This allows use of the /.default scope and the Azure portal's "Grant admin consent" option.

You can follow this process:

> 1.Go to your application in the Azure portal – App registrations experience, or create an app if you haven't already.
>
> 2.Locate the API Permissions section, and within the API permissions
>   click Add a permission.
>
> 3.Select Microsoft Graph from the list of available APIs and then add
>   the permissions that your app requires.
>
> 4.Save the app registration.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll +1 it because it is useful information, but it's not directly applicable to my case, for which I'm creating a new application.